# error when i use resize() library in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, error-handling, resize

I want to resize image when the controller receive fileimage from view this is my code

```
$this->load->library('upload');
$config[''image_library] = GD2;             
$config['upload_path'] = $path ;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '1024';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';
$config['encrypt_name'] = 'true';
$config['width'] = 200;
$config['height'] = 200;
$this->upload->initialize($config);
$this->upload->resize();
if(!$this->upload->resize()){
   echo $this->upload->display_error();
}
```

My error is

```
Call to undefined method CI_Upload::resize()
```

Thank you

Comment: There is a small mistake for the configuration option *image_library*.

Answer (score 0):

Error : $config[''image_library] = GD2;

```
$config['image_library'] = GD2;
```

Load the image manipulation class:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
```

Error: `$this->upload->resize();
if(!$this->upload->resize()){
   echo $this->upload->display_error();
}`

```
if( !$this->upload->do_upload() ){
    print_r( $this->upload->display_errors() );
}else{
    $this->image_lib->resize();
}
```